# Assigning values to static final variables

Tags: java, static

```
public class A{
    public static final int j;
    public static int x; 
    static{ 
         j=9; 
    }
    public A(int j)
    {
         j = j;
    }
    protected void print()
    {
           System.out.println(j);
    }
}
```

When trying code above in the eclipse, eclipse shows that "The assignment to variable j has no effect" is shown for intializing the vaiable "j" in the constructor.

Please do tell me why the variable j has no effect.

Comment: what is this code supposed to do anyway? I don't think it will do what you want it to.

Comment: final variables cannot change later, that's the point of being final, if you declare it non static, then you ought initialize it inside the constructor, BUT if you use the same varname as an argument or local variable, then you have to call the specific reference to the instance variable, in this case A.j or this.j if j wasn't static.

Answer (score 6):

The parameter `j` is *shadowing* the class member `j`. Try to change your code as follows:

```
public A(int j)
{
     A.j = j;
}
```

Comment: @UNECS Static members belong to the class, not to an instance.

Answer (score 4):

The class variable j (static final int j) is assigned the value 9 in the static block.  That is all valid.

In the constructor, the parameter j, is assigned to itself and that has no effect.  The alternative (and I suspect what you meant) is:

```
public A(int j)
{
     A.j = j;
}
```

Here the parameter j is assigned to the class variable j.  However, Java will complain here as the class variable is final.  If you remove the final keyword, this will of course work as well.  However, now it gets interesting:

The value of class j, will be 9 as long as no instance of class A is created.  The moment an instance of the class is created through the new operator, all instances of the class A will have the same value for the class variable j (dependant on what you sent the constructor).

Answer (score 3):

Assigning a variable to itself has the nett value of doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Because `final` variables can be assigned a value only once which means once during the execution of the JVM for a `static` variable, whereas the constructor is executed every time an object is created.

Comment: if so then it should display an error saying that the final field j may already have been assigned but it does not display but this is not the case with the instance variable.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a read at [this](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=310264). It says that in certain cases, *the warning generated is incorrect* , as in your case.

Comment: This holds only for `volatile` variables, which is not the case here.

Comment: It says that eclipse will generate such a warning whenever it sees an occurence of something on the lines of `x = x;` . But it is not correct in every case. They justify by giving an example of `volatile` variable. But as visible in this case, here it should have prompted with an error like `final field may already have been assigned` or something like that.

Comment: No. In the article you linked, it says: "yet in the case that the variable is volatile, the warning is incorrect". No volatiles are used here.

Comment: The article reports a bug in eclipse with a specific example. I think it holds valid for cases that were not discussed in the article, which is pretty much visible with the case we have in hand.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The case we have in hand is caused by shadowing. Please read the other answers to this question.

Comment: -1: The warning is **correct**. He overwrites the **local** j with **itself**, not the class member `j`.

Answer (score 0):

Do use `this.j = j;`

While useing `j = j`, the two "j"s are the same, just the parameter of the constructor, but not the field of Class A. If you want the field j of A, please use `this.j`.

Comment: Or `A.j`, as it is a class member, not an instance member.